# React ругается на символ "?"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, webpack

`currentQuestion?.questions.length` при использовании такого кода реакт выдает ошибку

```
./src/pages/quiz/Quiz.jsx 105:30
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (105:30)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Но если заменить на `currentQuestion.questions.length`, то ошибка пропадает.

Я так понял, что проблема в вебпаке ?
Как можно починить?

Из конфига вебпака:

```
loader: "babel-loader",
options: {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
}
```

Из конфига .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Comment: Какая версия `react-scripts`?

Comment: "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",

Comment: Обновите его > 3.3.0 версии и будет вам счастье

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем-то решил проблему максимально логичным и простым способом - пересобрал все через react-create-app.